# MySQL: Return fields where COUNT(*) is greater than 

Tags: database, mysql

I've got the following SQL, but I only want to return rows where 'hits' are greater than 10.

```
SELECT clicks.affiliate, COUNT(*) AS hits, affiliates.title, affiliates.url
FROM clicks
INNER JOIN affiliates ON affiliates.id = clicks.affiliate
GROUP BY clicks.affiliate
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To filter by an aggregate you need to use the `having` clause. Unlike many RDBMSs MySQL does allow you to use the column alias in this context (Most other RDBMSs would also insist on `affiliates.title, affiliates.url` being added to the `group by` clause as well)

```
SELECT clicks.affiliate, COUNT(*) AS hits, affiliates.title, affiliates.url
FROM clicks
INNER JOIN affiliates ON affiliates.id = clicks.affiliate
GROUP BY clicks.affiliate
HAVING hits > 10
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT clicks.affiliate, COUNT(*) AS hits, affiliates.title, affiliates.url
FROM clicks
INNER JOIN affiliates ON affiliates.id = clicks.affiliate
GROUP BY clicks.affiliate
HAVING COUNT(*) > 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ...
HAVING hits > 10
```